# Error using free in objective C

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, free

I'm reading a book called "programming in objective-c" by Stephen Kochan. I've been reading through it and I've copied some of the code down directly from the book into my program. The only problem I'm having is using free on an object. My code is as follows (and I'm sorry for putting the entire program in, but I am a noob so there is a good chance that I'm doing something wrong earlier on in the program):

```
//
//  main.m
//  prog1
//
//  Created by Brent Blackwood on 8/7/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 Brent Blackwood. All rights reserved.
//

#import <stdio.h> 
#import <objc/Object.h> 

//------- @interface section -------

@interface Fraction: NSObject {
    int numerator;
    int denominator;
}

-(void) print;
-(void) setNumerator: (int) n;
-(void) setDenominator: (int) d;

@end

//------- @implementation section -------

@implementation Fraction;

-(void) print{
    printf (" %i/%i ", numerator, denominator);
}

-(void) setNumerator: (int) n {
    numerator = n;
}

-(void) setDenominator: (int) d {
    denominator = d;
}

@end

//------- program section -------

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {


    // Create an instance of a Fraction

    Fraction *myFraction = [Fraction new];

    // Set fraction to 1/3

    [myFraction setNumerator: 1];
    [myFraction setDenominator: 3];

    // Display the fraction using the print method

    printf ("The value of myFraction is:");

    [myFraction print];
    printf ("\n");
    [myFraction free]; // ************---This is the line giving the error.---***********


    return 0;

}
```

The error I'm getting is "No visible @interface for 'Fraction' declares the selector 'free'" after the line "[myFraction free]";. I've looked through the book and can't figure out what the problem is. It makes no mention of this error. What does this mean and how can I fix it?

I've also looked at some similar questions here on stack before I asked but their problems don't seem to be the error that I'm running into. Please help. Thanks!

Comment: All the program is supposed to do is make a "fraction" object and print it out. The outcome is just a line of text stating the fraction.

Comment: I've also tried using - Fraction *myFraction = [[Fraction alloc]init]; instead of "new" but that doesn't work either and I don't know if that would make a difference anyway.

Comment: When I run the program without that line of code, it executes without any errors, but I'd like to get in the habit of good programming and efficient programming and the book said freeing up objects after they are used is good habit.

Comment: The method `[X new]` is equivalent to `[[X alloc] init]`, so there's no real difference between the two.  (It's not required to be the same, but it's the same by convention.)

Comment: You are using an **ancient** version of the book.  `free` existed prior to the creation of `NSObject` as the new base class in 1993.   Get an updated book!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In objective C you do not use free to release an allocated instance of an object.  free is only to be used when you called "malloc".

In objective C [MyClass new] is not equivalent to malloc, its equivalent to

```
MyClass *anInstance = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

This object is "freed" using the following

```
[anInstance release];
```

Cheers

Comment: also the syntax for free is free(aPtr); not [obj free];

Comment: Thanks user, I just tried your answer. Again I met with an error. "ARC forbids explicit message send of 'release'".

Comment: You didnt say you were using ARC - dont bother releasing it at all ARC will do it for you.  Cheers! - (ARC inserts release statements into the code for you)

Comment: okay thanks... Sorry I'm a noob and I don't even know what ARC is. I didn't even know I was using it. I just followed the instructions in the book. ^_^ Thanks though, your answer was very clear and informative.

Comment: `release` isn't really the same meaning as `free`; the former only moves the object closer to being deallocated.

Comment: unless its an autorelease instance it will in fact be freed if the retain count is 1

Comment: Thanks jesse for the syntax fixup!

Comment: Maybe you would like to check: [This Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html) to learn about Automatic Reference Counting (ARC)

Comment: Thanks for all your help everyone! Some good info and resources here!

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a non-Cocoa, non-Apple variant of Objective-C, due to the different conventions for allocating and freeing objects. Xcode strictly enforces Apple's own (Cocoa) conventions, which is why you're getting the error.

If you're looking to learn iOS (or Mac) programming without being sidetracked by learning Objective-C in its purist form, I'd try a different book.